# Understanding Illegal Generic Cast

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I'm having some trouble understanding why a cast I'm performing is throwing runtime exceptions stating that it's an illegal cast.  I did a bit of research and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12366064/2359643), which lead me to the MSDN article [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).  However, I'm still a bit confused so if anyone can help clarify it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the object hiearchy for 2 class types:

```
IMongoEntity (interface)
  |   - MongoEntity (abstract)
  |     |    -SalesProject (concrete)
  |     |    -ManagementProject (concrete)
```

---

```
IEntityService<T> where T : IMongoEntity (interface)
  |      -EntityService<T> where T : IMongoEntity (concrete superclass)
  |       |    - MgmtService : EntityService<ManagementProject> (subclass)
  |       |    - SalesService : EntityService<SalesProject> (subclass)
```

The two non generic services were only created so I could create some specific methods that only apply to those specific types (predefined lookups into the db essentially).

I then have this line, which throws the `InvalidCastException`:

```
IEntityService<IMongoEntity> service = fromsales ? 
    (IEntityService<IMongoEntity>)salesService : 
    (IEntityService<IMongoEntity>)mgmtService;
```

Since both services are derived from the same interfaces & abstract classes and the type parameters used are derived from the same abstract class, then why is this cast illegal?

NOTE:  I have workarounds for this, so I'm not really looking for a solution, but instead I want to understand *why* this is not allowed.

Comment: if `IEntityService<T> where T : IMongoEntity` was changed to `IEntityService<out T> where T : IMongoEntity` I think it would work. You are running in to covariance isues

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Isn't the out keyword in generics for return types though?  The methods all return Task<bool> or Task

Comment: Imagine `IEntityService<T>` has an `Add(T item)` method. (We don't know whether or not it does, but the compiler doesn't care. It *could*.) Now think what that means for an `IEntityService<IMongoEntity>` - you can add *any* mongo entity to it. Now, can you add a `ManagementProject` to a `SalesService`? Nope... *That's* why it's invalid.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, it's so simple!  That makes sense.

Comment: And `out` is what tells the compiler that you do not have any `Add(T item)` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyType<Base>` and `MyType<Derived>` do not have any inheritance relationship, even if `Derived` derives from `Base`. The two generic types are just two different types.

One way to come around this problem is to have a non-generic interface as base interface:

```
public interface IEntityService
{
    void DoSomething(object item);
}

public interface IEntityService<T> : IEntityService
{
    void DoSomething(T item);
}
```

This pattern is used in the .Net Class Library (for e.g. `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>`, `IList`/`IList<T>`).

If you know that your interface uses the generic type (`T`) only for outputs, you can use the `out` keyword `IMyInterface<out T>`. You can then provide a more derived type for `T`. This is called covariance. The return values of the methods will then yield a more derived type as expected by the consumer and this is ok.

If it uses the generic type only for inputs, use the `in` keyword `IMyInterface<in T>`. You can then provide a less derived type for `T`. This is called contravariance. The input arguments of the methods will then get a more derived type as expected and this is ok.