# Cast to object from generic interface returns null

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core, inversion-of-control

I have this situation

```
interface INotification<T>
{
    Task Handle(T t)
}
```

and multiple implementations

```
class Notification1 : INotification<SomeEvent>
{
    //.... 
}


class Notification2 : INotification<SomeEvent>
{
    //.... 
}
```

I'm using  ServiceProvider's `GetServices(Type)` to get all the implementations
as such

```
async Task RunAsync<TNotification>(TNotification notification)
{
    Type notificationType = notification.GetType();

    var handlerType = typeof(INotification<>).MakeGenericType(notificationType);

    var handlers = _serviceProvider.GetServices(handlerType);

    foreach (var handler in handlers)
    {
        var instance = handler as INotification<TNotification>;

        await instance.Handle(notification);
    }
}
```

in `handlers` I get the handlers that implement `INotification<T>` In the foreach loop I'm trying to do a cast to `INotification` and trigger the Handle method.

But the cast fails

```
var instance = handler as INotification<TNotification>;
```

I get *null*.

What's the problem with my code ?

Comment: What's the type of `handlers`? And `handler`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what the *actual* type of your handler is?

Comment: The **handlerType is {INotificationHandler`1[Events.SomeEvent]}** and the handler is  **{.EventHandlers.Notification1 }**

Comment: You should not use `as` to cast something when you have written the code such that you expect the cast to always succeed.  You should use a regular cast.  You *want* your code to throw an exception if the types don't match, because it's a bug in your code if they don't match.  You even get the bonus of having the error message tell you why the types don't match.  `as` is something to use when you don't know if the conversion will succeed or not, and it's valid in your situation for the type to not match.

Comment: `ISome<Derived>` **is not** `ISome<Base>` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365993/c-sharp-casting-an-inherited-generic-interface have all links to information you need to read about that (also may not apply directly to the question)

Comment: Side note: please check out [MCVE] guidance - you really don't need all this reflection/GetService code to show that cast from instance of one type to some other type fails - that could also help to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the constructed generic type,

```
var handlerType = typeof(INotification<>).MakeGenericType(notificationType);
```

I believe there may be some confusion with the generics.

Consider using the generic `GetServices<T>()` extension for the service provider which would simplify the above code to.

```
async Task RunAsync<TEvent>(TEvent @event) {
    var handlers = _serviceProvider.GetServices<INotification<TEvent>>();    
    foreach (var handler in handlers) {
        await handler.Handle(@event);
    }
}
```

Because of the strongly typed generics it simplifies the call to the handlers as they will already be of the desired type

This can also be refactored to handle all the notifications asynchronously using `Task.WhenAll` instead of sequentially like in the `foreach` loop

```
async Task RunAsync<TEvent>(TEvent @event) {
    var handlers = _serviceProvider.GetServices<INotification<TEvent>>();
    if(handlers.Any()) {
        var tasks = handlers.Select(handler => handler.Handle(@event));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `var instance = handler as INotification<TNotification>;` look very strange. It looks like you'd normally have `TNotification` as some sort of notification class like `Notification1`. So resulting cast is

```
    handler as INotification<Notification1>
```

which indeed will fail as code seem to be creating `handlerType`to be of `TNotification`( `Notification1` in sample case) which will normally not be `Notification1 : INotificaton<Notification1>` (also possible - [Recursive generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647533/recursive-generic-types)).

You probably want something like

```
async Task RunAsync<TNotification, TEvent>(TNotification notification)
       where TNotification : INotification<TEvent>
{
    ...
    var instance = (INotification<TEvent>)handler;
    …
}
```

Note that you must specify event type (`TEvent`) as single class may implement multiple interface like

```
class NightWatch :
   INotification<ArrowEvent>, INotification<GunEvent>, INotification<OwlEvent>
{}
```

and there is no way to figure out which one to cast to based on just class.