# Error casting class to its interface with generic type (when also casting generic type to its base)

Tags: c#, casting

Hello I have the next problem casting classes. I have a Quest class that others inherit

```
public class Quest{}

public class QuestChild: Quest{}
```

I use a generic validator that expects to receive some type of Quest

```
public interface IQuestValidator<in T> where T:Quest
{
    bool IsCompleted(T quest);

    bool IsFailed(T quest);
}

public class QuestValidator<T>: IQuestValidator<T> where T: Quest
{    
    public bool IsCompleted(T quest)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsFailed(T quest)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I create the validator for each derived class of Quest, I want to cast it to its Base clase like this:

```
    IQuestValidator<Quest> c = (IQuestValidator<Quest>)new QuestValidator<QuestChild>();
```

But when I execute this line, it returns the error "InvalidCastException". Why this happens or how could I solve this to cast correctly?

Note: It seems similar to this question [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase), but since I'm not using IEnumerable I can't do the same.

Comment: Why are you performing the cast at all, and not just declaring it as IQuestValidator<QuestChild> c  (or var)?

Comment: @Metheny I want to cast it to generic IQuestValidator<Quest> because I have an "injector" that based on a type it returns that generic class, like this refs = new Dictionary<Type, IQuestValidator<Quest>>(); and I need all Quest validator have a common interface

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365993/c-sharp-casting-an-inherited-generic-interface and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance#InterfaceCovariantTypeParameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase)

Comment: Thanks @Greg. I think my case is different from the questions that use List, but the first link is near of what I'm trying to do, but I use Quest as Class and in that example Quest would be an interface. I will try it and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding class is invariant, so there's no way the cast would be possible!
Try rethinking your design to remove the demand for the desired cast.